# Check for Wordpress Thumbnail and display dummy if not there

Tags: php, wordpress

got another question to ask:

I would like to display post thumbnails with the post title underneath. I have managed to work that out through asking on here, however now I would like to add a function that checks for a thumbnail and if none is available displays a dummy image.

Here is my try, which does display the thumbnail (if there) but not the dummy (if no thumbnail is attached):

```
<div class="gallery_container_wrapper">
<?php query_posts( $args ); if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
    <div class="gallery_image_container">
        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>">
            <div class="gallery_image_thumb">
                <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) { 
                    the_post_thumbnail('thumbnail'); }
                else {
                    echo 
                    '<img src="http://www.kunstamkasten.de/wp-content/uploads/2014/08/gallery_dummy.jpg" />'
                ; } ?>

            </div>
            <div class="gallery_title">
                <h2>
                    <?php the_title(); ?>
                </h2>
            </div>
        </a>
    </div>
<?php endwhile; else : ?>
    <p><?php _e( 'Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.' ); ?></p>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
</div>
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code works for me.  Yours is virtually identical.

```
<?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) : ?>

        <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>

    <?php else : ?>

  <img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/images/sunlit_path_banner.jpg" alt="Sunlit Path" />

    <?php endif; ?>
```

Note:   I also cut and pasted your code and tested on my WP install, and it worked fine.

Or... try this alternative to the if condition:

```
<?php if ( get_the_post_thumbnail( get_the_ID() ) ) { 
                    the_post_thumbnail('thumbnail'); }
                else {
                    echo 
                    '<img src="http://www.kunstamkasten.de/wp-content/uploads/2014/08/gallery_dummy.jpg" />'
                ; } ?>
```

Comment: Hm, I tried writing it like this as well, but to no avail... It almost seems like it thinks there is a thumbnail but then cant load it (because it isnt there)...

Edit: Any idea where it might come from that it doesnt on mine? Everythings up to date and the if works, just the else doesnt...

Comment: Is it possible there IS actually a featured image on the pages you're checking?

Comment: There are some threads on the Wordpress support site about this issue... has_post_thumbnail() reports "true" when no featured image is set.  http://wordpress.org/support/topic/has_post_thumbnail-returns-true-no-image-featured-image

Comment: Thanks for telling me about that Pagerange... Is there any way to avoid this reporting as true or should I do it another way and if so, how would I do that?

Comment: Try this:  if ( get_the_post_thumbnail( get_the_ID() ) )  instead of has_post_thumbnail()     This will return an empty string for the filename if there is no post thumbnail, which will resolve to false.   Just added the code snippet to the answer.

Comment: Thanks! This has solved my problem too. I came across from Google when i searching for similar results.